# How change WordPress to use avatar from a intranet?

Tags: wordpress

I'm try add an option to use avatar from local network:

```
function tilt_avatar_defaults ( $avatar_defaults ) {
    $avatar = 'https://users.secret.local/avatar/' . strtoupper( wp_get_current_user()->user_login );
    $avatar_defaults[$avatar] = 'Users Company';

    return $avatar_defaults;
}
add_filter('avatar_defaults', 'tilt_avatar_defaults');
```

But the result are calling `http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/`:

```
http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/90d40252e7696abaf764c11d68800999?s=96&d=https%3A%2F%2Fusers.secret.local%2Favatar%2Fbrunowego&r=g
```

How resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try filtering the output Avatar using filter `get_avatar`

[Filter Get Avatar](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_avatar/)

While the below may not be the perfect answer, it should get you where you want to be.

```
add_filter('get_avatar', 'dd_get_avatar', 10, 4);
function dd_get_avatar($avatar, $id, $size, $default){
    $avatar = '<img src="'.$default.'" class="avatar avatar-64 photo" height="64" width="64" />';
    return $avatar;
}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

To use function `get_avatar_data` there is a hook also for `get_avatar_data` which passes the `$args` including the Avatar URL.

```php
add_filter('get_avatar_data', 'dd_get_avatar_data', 10, 2);
function dd_get_avatar_data($args, $id_or_email){
    // Check if it's an ID or an email
    if (is_numeric($id_or_email)){
        $user = get_user_by('ID', $id_or_email);
    } else {
        $user = get_user_by('email', $id_or_email);
    }
    // Set the Avatar URL
    $args['url'] = 'https://users.secret.local/avatar/' . strtoupper($user->user_login);
    return $args;
}
```

Doing this would force all avatars to use your custom URL, and you wouldn't have to set the default.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking a way to manipulate the function `get_avatar_data` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_data/